# What is the name of the default Desktop Environment of Ubuntu Studio 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, ubuntu-studio

Surprisingly I can't find its name anywhere though from screenshots it's something like lxde, xfce gnome2, but which one is it really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia

> "Default user interface   Xfce (formerly GNOME)" - By [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) under [Ubuntu Studio - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Studio)

And SoftPedia:

> "... It combines the snappiness of the Xfce desktop environment with the
>   stable base of the popular Ubuntu distribution..." - By [SoftPedia](http://www.softpedia.com/) under [Ubuntu Studio  14.04.1 LTS for Linux - Softpedia](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Linux-Distributions/Ubuntu-Studio-Trusty-Tahr-103368.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu studio 13.10 was using xfce as default. I guess this is still the case...